# Is there a way to build a graph in Gephi and export it to TitanDb?

Tags: titan, tinkerpop, gephi, graphml

Is there a way to build a graph using Gephi with the Data Laboratory and export it to titan db?

I tried the following without success: 
Built a simple graph in Gephi with the Data Laboratory
Saved the graph as GraphML format
Used the titanDb's Gremlin console to import the graphml file.
I got this error: Name cannot be in protected namespace: label

edit: using TitanDb 1.0.0 over aws DynamoDb

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Titan 1.0 uses Apache TinkerPop 3.0.1 for its core Graph API, so the actual functionality is from TinkerPop, [documented here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_graphml_reader_writer). It sounds like you're already aware of this. Here's an [example GraphML file](https://gist.github.com/pluradj/90ff3d62e69b2d60212787da44986c7a) that will load successfully using `graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('tinkerpop-classic-indented.xml')`

One aspect that isn't currently documented with TinkerPop's specific usage of GraphML is that it requires `labelV` and `labelE` data keys in `<node>` and `<edge>` respectively.

In my brief testing with the Gephi 0.9.1 Data Laboratory, when you create a node, it prompts you to set a `label`. This creates a `label` data key in `<node>` in the GraphML. When you create an edge, it prompts you to set a `kind`, which doesn't actually appear in the GraphML. You should set a `label` on the edge after it is created. This creates an `edgelabel` data key in the GraphML.

Titan / TinkerPop requires labels on all nodes and edges, so make sure a non-empty `label` is set for all.

After you export your graph as a GraphML file from Gephi

1. Replace All in the file to change `"label"` to `"labelV"`. If you don't do this, you would hit the error (`Name cannot be in protected namespace: label`) in your original post because `label` is a [reserved word](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/types/system/SystemTypeManager.java#L41) in Titan.
2. Replace All in the file to change `"edgelabel"` to `"labelE"`. If you don't do this, you'll run into an error saying `Label can not be null`.

Then the file is ready for loading into Titan.